# How are JCenter and Maven Central coordinates different from one another?

Tags: java, gradle, maven-central, jcenter, lazybones

I am trying to include [LazyBones](https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones), which is [stored here in Bintray/JCenter](https://bintray.com/pledbrook/lazybones-templates/lazybones/0.8.1/view) in my Gradle project as a compile-time dependency, like so:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.12'
    compile 'org.codemonkey.simplejavamail:simple-java-mail:2.3'
    compile 'pledbrook/lazybones-templates:lazybones:0.8.1'     // <-- here
}
```

I have tried many other combination/permutations of group/artifact names for the `0.8.1` version, but nothing is working/resolving. This is the first time I’ve ever (intentionally) tried depending on a compile binary that is *only* stored in JCenter, and not available via Maven Central. So I ask: what’s the difference between Maven Central and JCenter coordinates, and what do I need to do so that Gradle can “find” the LazyBones JAR living in JCenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with [this Lazybones artifact](https://bintray.com/pledbrook/lazybones-templates/lazybones/0.8.1/view#files) is that it's not a maven artifact. It's a zip, not in maven layout, and from what I know about Lazybones it's not supposed to be used directly as a dependency from Gradle/Maven.
That's why you can't use the normal coordinates.

Comment: Ahhh, makes sense @JBaruch (+1) - so can I assume this means that I'd have to fashion my own POM and host LazyBones on my own (say) Artifactory repo in order to pull it in with the Gradle build?

Comment: I'd say you should check that you use lazybones correctly. I am pretty sure it's not intended to be a runtime dependency. From what I know about it, you run to create a project, not during work on the project.

Comment: Yeah Im using it correctly for my use case, I need its templating capabilities, not the user-friendly command line tool!

Comment: Got it. Not sure if it is embeddable as it it's. You might want to contact the author about that.

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones/issues/63) to make it embeddable.